# Rotate object when colliding

Tags: particles, rigid-body-simulation, collision

I have a question regarding collisions in blender.

I'm trying to animate shortwave radiation (particle system) which reflects on different materials.

However when i apply a collision the 'solar rays' (shortwave) do not rotate when they collide with the material (see figure).

[image]

I've tried to add a rigid body to the cilinder (ray), but it does not seem to work...

can anyone help me out here? Really appreciate it!

Comment: Oke I figured out a way to make te particles rotate when colliding by using LINE under the RENDER tab in the particle system properties. However when using the LINE tab, I'm not able to change the scale of the particles... Does anyone know how to change this?

Comment: LINE is not rendered in cycles render... :( I'm lost now..